# How to scale projection matrix?

Tags: calibration, computer-vision, cameras, camera-calibration

I was going through the [camera calibration lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUbWsXU1mac) by professor Shree Nayar.

At [4:49](https://youtu.be/GUbWsXU1mac?si=x_xLdhuTApXPw-tW&t=289), he is :

> Scaling the projection matrix implies simultaneously scalign the world and the camera, which does not change the image. Thus, we can set the scale of the projection matrix arbitrarily.
> Given following 3D to 2D mapping:
> $$
> \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c}
> u^{(i)} \\
> v^{(i)} \\
> 1
> \end{array}\right]}_{\text{known image coordinates}}
>  \equiv
> \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{llll}
> p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13} & p_{14} \\
> p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23} & p_{24} \\
> p_{31} & p_{32} & p_{33} & p_{34}
> \end{array}\right]}_{\text{unknown projection matrix}}
> \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c}
> x_w^{(i)} \\
> y_w^{(i)} \\
> z_w^{(i)} \\
> 1
> \end{array}\right]}_{\text{known world coordinates}}
> $$
> we cane two ways to scale projection matrix:
>
> 1. Set the scale so that $p_{34}=1$
> 2. Set the scale so that $\Vert p\Vert^2=1$

I understand given homogenous coordinates of a point $$P_h=\left[\begin{array}{c}
u \\
v \\
w
\end{array}\right]$$
we can obtain the non-homogenous coordinates as:
$$P=\left[\begin{array}{c}
u/w \\
v/w \\
w/w
\end{array}\right]$$

But my stupid eyes are not able to make clear sense of two stated ways of scaling the projection matrix. Exactly how ensuring just the last element $p_{34}=1$ or norm of matrix $\Vert p\Vert^2=1$ is enough to scale the whole projection matrix?